# I need flexslider caption in fadeIn and images in slide animation

Tags: fadein, slide, flexslider, caption

I need flexslider caption in fadeIn animation and images in slide animation is this possible to do, plz help me out.

Here is the code i am using

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
animation: "slide", touch: true, smoothHeight: true,
 after: function(slider) {
     //alert(slider);
         // animate your caption ... 
         // find the item that is the current slide's .slidecaption and animate it
         $('.flex-active-slide').find('.flex-caption .services_links').fadeIn(300).delay(800);
      }// auto-adjust to fit the height of images
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a pull that can help you 
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/pull/865
good luck